# What are "islands" on circuit diagrams?

Tags: schematics

On many schematics I saw areas, which are apparently not connected to other parts of the scheme.

For example, below is a part of Arduino Uno diagram:

[image]

As you see, below are two "islands" which are not connected to other parts.

What are they mean?

Comment: Are you talking about the crystals?

Comment: Crystal Q1 is connected to capacitors C9 and C11 and to GND and to nothing else. Why?

Comment: I think they are trying to show three different options for the crystal connections.  Are there any notes on the schematic or other documentation about this?  I'd expect something like "Use {these components} or {these other components}..."

Comment: If you weren't able to understand it at a glance, if this part of schematic made you decipher it, then it's not well drawn.  It would have been an improvement if they have drawn a frame around these optional parts and added a title "Optional crystal footprints (not populated)".

Comment: It's a lousy and messy diagram, with lots of mistakes. Don't look at it for guidance on how to interpret a schematic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, circuit diagrams use global signals to avoid the visual clutter that having wires connecting *everything* would cause. Those two islands have a GND terminal, and the pin names XT1 ... XTAL2. That's where they connect.

Answer (score 3):

Those net labels that have been added to the traces are not just for your information- they are typically used to show connectivity **within a single sheet** (at least that's their scope in Altium) without the clutter of showing actual lines.

[image]

[image]

Comment: On Eagle CAD (probably the program this schematic was made in) they can show connections to other sheets as well. They show the sheet numbers they are connected to after the text, i.e.: XT1/.2 (not sure if the slash/period are in the right order but its something close to that)

Comment: @WesleyLee That's a different, but pretty decent, way to do it. So these particular ones must be on the single sheet because no .x.